Wordpress widget of products empty
I am working with wordpress, Elementor and Woocomerce. After make an update of all my products, basically I deleted them and I created new ones, in my product page, the widget "products" is now empty (image attached), products are not shown up. The widget is there but empty.
Why is this happening?
product widget
I have been created a new widget to see if works and then the products are shown in the new widget. I need to keep the old widget because i have a lot of CSS created for it

Your widget may need to be configured to take in the products as they are essentially new products after deleting and recreating. Can you update your question with any code or configuration info?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

SOLVED
The issue was in the query of the widget in the config section, where query tab is located. In the query tab, it was selected as source "manual selection" instead "latest products"
